# remove files based upon diff of two text files

Tags: bash, text-processing, files, grep

I have created two .txt files that look like:

```
5fba026dcf271c6fa174b9fc2fc1fefadf1370f9 ./.changeFiles/change/addImage1.change  
bb352fba5807f4d03ea11abb00e411b00ce38673  ./.changeFiles/change/addImage2.change  
999eea42e4e72431695815456a3ac16796df5eed  ./.changeFiles/change/addSurface1.change
```

One is a list of all files that end with .change or .tstwf in the given directory and the other is a sorted version of that list with duplicate entries (based on the shasum) removed.

When I use a colordiff -u on the two files all the changes are the files I want removed. There are hundreds of files to be removed and I would prefer not to have to do it manually...

So my question is: How do I remove the files from the directory that are not included in the sorted.txt and show up in the diff?

Edit1:

workflows.txt (original file):

```
23ded53098d5d233c0a54af482542ba7a42860d3  ./encryption/AFPtoPDFwEncryption.tstwf
24a37e00de73a58736be1aee56d4b073e75a994f  ./workflows-from-will/workflow/AFPtoPDF.tstwf
2532934d268bb6eddc6a018e3469b0a53a794e10  ./workflows-from-will/workflow/change/table.without.emptycells.rotation.270.mark-content.change
264a08fef59d9b9c18a857e2532f0b7b5a92c60b  ./pageModification/AFPtoPDFwFillRectMod1.tstwf
2680a37bb22512bf3119e3991bb2c814cb23fb77  ./workflows-from-will/workflow/AFPtoPDFwHyperlinks.tstwf
268635261e91a4caf1a09979ffdb8163d4d22c8a  ./AFPmicr.tstwf
268635261e91a4caf1a09979ffdb8163d4d22c8a  ./workflows-from-will/eds-0923/AFPmicr.tstwf
```

workflows-sorted.txt (list of all files of this type to be kept):

```
0bdbcbed279e2df9149de319253609f11b19d689  ./textModification/AFPtoPDFwReplaceTextMod2.tstwf
0d0ebfb8d519ff84e3dd86771d067bdeea835df6  ./pageModification/AFPtoPDFwSoftClipMod1.tstwf
0dcafe876ea8574619664920ec5b1fdbff3ca218  ./workflows-from-will/AFPtoPDF_CE003A01.tstwf
0e55506bf5d7694d8cda9467a5809ea75c486fb1  ./workflows-from-will/workflow/change/pdf.change
0ec03992e19a12520f131f89cd9060c2e4ba2be2  ./workflows-from-will/AFPNOPIndexCallback.tstwf
0f1dca3e5d9b17f11c194b250096fc15891b9998  ./stapling/AFPtoPDFwStapling1.tstwf
```

Also, further in my research I came across the command "comm" it seems like this could be used to isolate the files I want removed.

Comment: Could you provide a list (with 5 or so lines) of **each** file, So we could run local tests?.

Comment: Surely, you will get a more meaningful diff if you compare the *sorted* version of the original list, against the sorted list with the dupes removed. Diff sorted against sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to remove the files listed in `workflows.txt`, except for those that are listed in `workflows-sorted.txt`. You can obtain the list of files by stripping off the checksums, sorting the names and running [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) to extract the lines that are only present in `workflows.txt`. In a shell that supports process substitution (ksh93, bash, zsh):

```
comm -23 <(<workflows.txt sed 's/^[^ ]*[ ][ ]*//' | sort) \
         <(workflows-sorted.txt sed 's/^[^ ]*[ ][ ]*//' | sort)
```

`comm -23` removes the lines that are only present in the second argument (`-2`) and the lines that are present in both files (`-3`), thus keeping only the lines that are present in the first argument but not the second argument. Keep in mind that `comm` requires the input files to be sorted.

To delete them:

```
comm -23 <(<workflows.txt sed 's/^[^ ]*[ ][ ]*//' | sort) \
         <(workflows-sorted.txt sed 's/^[^ ]*[ ][ ]*//' | sort) |
xargs -I rm -- {}
```

You can make the last line `xargs rm` to go slightly faster (by grouping calls to `rm`) if the file names don't contain any whitespace or `\'"`. Alternatively you can make the last line `tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm --` or `xargs -d '\n' rm --` if your `xargs` supports these options. You don't need the `--` if all your file names begin with `/` or `./` (or anything that's guaranteed not to begin with `-`).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up editing the sed command to more accurately strip the checksum. From: `(<workflows.txt 'sed/^[^ *][ ][ ]*//' | sort)` To: `(sed 's/^[^ ]*  *//' workflows.txt | sort)` Also, the last line of `tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm --` worked the best for my case.

Answer (score 0):

If your filenames do not have spaces, this should give you a list of the repeated files you want to erase:

```
awk 'c[$1]++' workflows.txt > erasefiles.txt
```

Then, it is just a matter of erasing all of them (use echo first till you are sure this does exactly what you need) (in bash):

```
rm $(awk '{print $2}' erasefiles.txt)
```

If your files could have spaces (or other odd chars, except new line - `\n` and zero `\0` ):

```
awk '{$1=""; print}' erasefiles.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -r rm --
```

Answer (score 0):

For a *one off* job, I'd start with the `diff` output, and edit that into a list of files to delete (if bored, leave that task to `sed(1)`, a Perl script, or some such). After double-checking the list, run it off by e.g. (`bash(1)`!):

```
rm $(< list-of-files-to-axe)
```

Might season with `-f` or `-i` flags to taste.

Automating this will be a lot more work (and introduce too many gotchas) to be worth it for occasional use. For repetitive use, write it all in a capable scripting language, like Perl or Python. Stay away from special-purpose languages like `awk(1)`.